# Best alternative to Stop an Activity started from a Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I started an activity with the following code from my service:

```
Intent cmActivityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallManagementActivity.class);
cmActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(cmActivityIntent);
```

In the app's manifest the launchMode of the activity is defined as `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.

I've been looking for ways of stopping the activity on the service's `onDestroy()` but I haven't been able to find any documentation that can help me. And I've only found one way of doing it.

I've seen the aproach of checking on the serviceif the activity is instanced using an activity-class-static-property (`public static boolean isInstanced`) and sending another intent to the activity with a `FINISH_ACTIVITY` extra if it is. Then, on the activity's `onNewIntent()` the flag would be checked and the activity would be finished if the flag was included.

This approach doesn't feel right to me, since intents are supposed to be used start activities and not stopping them.

Does someone know any other way of how to acomplish this?

Comment: a broadcast would work, with a receiver in the activity. Alternatively, the activity could bind to the service, pass it a messenger, and the service would use the messenger to pass commands to the activity.

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager` or an Event Bus like `Otto` should be able to do it, then just call `finish()` on the event.

Comment: @njzk2 Could you post the binding alternative as a solution with an example code to try it and see if it works?

Comment: I approve of the method you mentioned in your post. I do this sort of thing all the time. `Intent`s are used in Android to communicate between components. They aren't only used to start activities. This is a perfectly legitimate purpose IMHO. Another alternative would be to send a broadcast `Intent` (as @njzk2 suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Many alternatives have been given to solve this issue:

- Use an `Intent` and set an `Extra`.
- Send a broadcast intent from the `Service` and register a `BroadcastReceiver` on the `Activity`.
- Use the `LocalBroadcastManager` (similar to previous alternative)
- Bind the `Activity` to the `Service` and pass it a `Messenger` so the `Service` can use it to communicate with the `Activity`.

None of them have I found a good solution, in fact, since the service is only accesible from the package, the solution I'm sticking with is the `Observer Pattern`.

Next you'll find the code I used. The activities implement the Observer interface (my own) and the service the abstract class ObservableService.

**ObservableService:**

```
public abstract class ObservableService extends Service {

@Override 
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    serviceStarted = true;
    observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    serviceStarted = false;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
//
// Singleton methods
//
//---------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Flag set to <code>true</code> if the service is running and 
 * <code>false</code> if not.
 */
private static boolean serviceStarted;

/**
 * Used to check if the service is started.
 * @return <code>true</code> if the service is running and <code>false</code>
 * if not.
 */
public static boolean isServiceStarted() {
    return serviceStarted;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
//
// Observable methods an constants
//
//---------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Used to notify the observers that the service has been stopped.
 */
public static String UPDATE_TYPE_SERVICE_STOPPED = "service_stopped";


protected static ArrayList<Observer> observers;


public static void addObserver(Observer observer) {
    observers.add(observer);
}

public static void removeObserver(Observer observer) {
    observers.remove(observer);
}

protected static void notifyObservers(String updateType) {
    for (Observer observer : observers) {
        observer.onObservableUpdate(updateType);
    }
}
```

}

**Observer:**

```
public interface Observer {

    public void onObservableUpdate(String updateType);

}
```

The activities just register themselves as observers at onResume() and unregister at onPause(). The `isServiceStarted()` is used to finish the activity if the service is already stopped.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (InCallService.isServiceStarted()) {
        InCallService.addObserver(this);
    } else {
        this.finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    InCallService.removeObserver(this);
}

public void onObservableUpdate(String updateType) {
    if (updateType.equals(ObservableService.UPDATE_TYPE_SERVICE_STOPPED)) {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

I chose this because I found it to be a very simple and high-performance alternative.